# Mingw static linking of different versions on different OS

Tags: ubuntu, centos, mingw, static-linking, mingw-w64

I am cross compiling a small project from linux to windows and I am using [ibpp](http://www.ibpp.org) to connect to a firebird DB.

The first OS is

- Ubuntu 21.04
- g++ (Ubuntu 10.3.0-1ubuntu1) 10.3.0
- x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ (GCC) 10-win32 20210408

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10-win32/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../../src/configure --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --includedir='/usr/include' --mandir='/usr/share/man' --infodir='/usr/share/info' --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --disable-option-checking --disable-silent-rules --libdir='/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' --libexecdir='/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' --disable-maintainer-mode --disable-dependency-tracking --prefix=/usr --enable-shared --enable-static --disable-multilib --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-tune=generic --with-headers=/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libgomp --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++,ada --enable-lto --enable-threads=win32 --program-suffix=-win32 --program-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --with-as=/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-as --with-ld=/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld --enable-libatomic --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts=yes --enable-dependency-tracking
Thread model: win32
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib
gcc version 10-win32 20210408 (GCC)
```

The second:

- CentOS Stream release 8
- g++ (GCC) 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-3)
- x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ (GCC) 7.2.0 20170814 (Fedora MinGW 7.2.0-2.el8)

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --includedir=/usr/include --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --datadir=/usr/share --build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --verbose --without-newlib --disable-multilib --disable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-nls --without-included-gettext --disable-win32-registry --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-threads=posix --enable-libgomp --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --with-sysroot=/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/c++
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.2.0 20170814 (Fedora MinGW 7.2.0-2.el8) (GCC)
```

On Ubuntu I compile like that:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ --static -Wall -DIBPP_WINDOWS con_test.cpp ../IBPP/core/all_in_one.cpp -o con_test.exe
```

If I omit `--static` the program does not run on windows because some DLLs are missing.

On CentOS I compile like this:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -Wall -DIBPP_WINDOWS con_test.cpp ibpp/core/all_in_one.cpp -o con_test.exe
```

and the program is running fine on windows. If I don't omit `--static` I get an error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthread
```

So my question is basically: Do I do everything correctly and this is because of the OS/compiler difference? Or is it just a fluke in centOS and I might get problems later on while running my program on windows? I would like my program to be static linked so I don't need to worry about DLLs.

Comment: The `Thread model` output of `x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -v` for both compilers might be interesting.

Comment: @ssbssa I edited the question with additional data